# Disable "Notify me when the clock changes" setting from CMD or Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In the `Date and Time` Control Panel Applet in Windows (regardless of version), there is a check box for stating *"Notify me when the clock changes"* . . .

I have scoured the internet and searched here as well, but cannot seem to pinpoint an answer.  ***Can this setting be enabled/disabled from the Command Line (or batch file, etc?)***  Current Windows Environment is Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019.

I also checked the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation` in hopes to use `reg` from the `Command Prompt` but did not see any changes when toggling.

Hoping this is simple to change, but the answer eludes me.

Comment: I would like to understand why this is considered off topic about "General computing hardware and software" - this was a pinpointed question of determining the specific registry keys in order to be toggled by a Command Prompt or Batch File command in order to accomplish a goal of checking a box programmatically without the GUI. . .

I can add this insight into the question, but I am also trying to learn how to be less verbose in my questions so they don't become a heap of "TLDR" skips. . .

Answer (score 3):

Looked through all the registry keys of `Control Panel` under `HKCU` hive and found `TimeDate`:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\TimeDate`

It shows a `DstNotification` as a `REG_DWORD` - set it to `0x00000001` to enable notifications, `0x00000000` to disable.

To do this via `Command Prompt`

You would use `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Timedate\ /v DstNotification /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f"` to force the change.